# PHP response empty after deploying build react project

Tags: reactjs, axios

After deploying the build folder of my react project, I tried to login but I notice that the session is empty. The output of my project are mostly errors since session is required in every page. I tried to debug and I found that my PHP file have no data response.

May I ask what's the problem with my code.
Here it is.

```
handleClick = event =>  {
event.preventDefault();

if (this.validateForm()) {
  let loginform = document.getElementById('login');
  let formData = new FormData(loginform);
  formData.append('username',this.state.username)
  formData.append('password',this.state.password)
  formData.append('company',this.state.company)
  formData.append('division',this.state.division)

  axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: this.getHostname()+'/new_vehicle_management/src/components/php/login.php',
  data: formData,
  config: 
  {
    //headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true', 
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Accept: "application/json"
  }}
  })
  .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data === "failed") {
           alert("Connection Failed.")
          }else if (response.data === "No Company") {
            alert("Company does not exist.")
           }else if (response.data === "No Division") {
            alert("Division does not exist.")
           }else if (response.data === "No User") {
            alert("Username does not exist.")
           }else if (response.data === "Not Match") {
            alert("Username and Password does not match.")
           }else if(response.data === "No Record"){
            alert("Invalid Credentials.");
           }
           else{
            alert("Login Successfully")
            localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(response.data))
            localStorage.setItem('user_id', JSON.stringify(response.data.user_id))
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data.user_full_name))
            localStorage.setItem('div_id', JSON.stringify(response.data.div_id))
            localStorage.setItem('comp_id', JSON.stringify(response.data.comp_id))
            window.location = "/menu"
           }
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response)
        });
}         
}
```

Comment: The problem would likely be in your PHP code, not the javascript

Comment: But in my local instance, it's working. The error only occured when I deployed it in production.

Comment: Yes but it is PHP that is not sending the response as you yourself mention

Comment: When I tried to debug and use console.log it returned {data: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset…s/main.c5c9f3bb.chunk.js"></script></body></html>"

Comment: The value of data should be the data from the database. But I got the html code calling the main js from build instead.